# Saving msg to local folder using illegal characters in file name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code to save emails from Outlook to a folder on the desktop.

I would like to name the files with the email subjects exactly the way they are in Outlook. I do not want to strip any characters.

I have played around with the macro but I can't fix it. Also would like to remove the time stamp date etc.

```
Option Explicit
Dim StrSavePath     As String

Sub SaveAllEmails_ProcessAllSubFolders()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim n               As Long
    Dim StrSubject      As String
    Dim StrName         As String
    Dim StrFile         As String
    Dim StrReceived     As String
    Dim StrFolder       As String
    Dim StrSaveFolder   As String
    Dim StrFolderPath   As String
    Dim iNameSpace      As NameSpace
    Dim myOlApp         As Outlook.Application
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    Dim mItem           As MailItem
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ChosenFolder    As Object
    Dim Folders         As New Collection
    Dim EntryID         As New Collection
    Dim StoreID         As New Collection

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ChosenFolder = iNameSpace.PickFolder
    If ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
'GoTo ExitSub:
    End If

BrowseForFolder StrSavePath

    Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)

    For i = 1 To Folders.Count
        StrFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
        n = InStr(3, StrFolder, "\") + 1
        StrFolder = Mid(StrFolder, n, 256)
        StrFolderPath = StrSavePath & "\" & StrFolder & "\"
        StrSaveFolder = Left(StrFolderPath, Len(StrFolderPath) - 1) & "\"
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(StrFolderPath) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (StrFolderPath)
        End If

        Set SubFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
        On Error Resume Next
        For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
            Set mItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
            StrReceived = Format(mItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD-hhmm")
            StrSubject = mItem.Subject
            StrName = StripIllegalChar(StrSubject)
            StrFile = StrSaveFolder & StrReceived & "_" & StrName & ".msg"
            StrFile = Left(StrFile, 256)
            mItem.SaveAs StrFile, 3
        Next j
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

ExitSub:

End Sub

Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    Dim RegX            As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True

    StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")

ExitFunction:
    Set RegX = Nothing

End Function


Sub GetFolder(Folders As Collection, EntryID As Collection, _
                        StoreID As Collection, Fld As MAPIFolder)
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder

    Folders.Add Fld.FolderPath
    EntryID.Add Fld.EntryID
    StoreID.Add Fld.StoreID
    For Each SubFolder In Fld.Folders
        GetFolder Folders, EntryID, StoreID, SubFolder
    Next SubFolder

ExitSub:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing

End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(StrSavePath As String, _
                        Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder '  As Folder

Dim enviro
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", _
                                           0, enviro & "C:\Temp\Folders")
StrSavePath = objFolder.self.Path

    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

ExitFunction:
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: `StripIllegalChar` is named that because certain characters *cannot* be used in a file name.  There's no getting away from that.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative approach if you absolutely want to retain the original email unaltered is to create a new email message to yourself with the original email saved as an attachment. Save the new email with a corrected subject to avoid windows naming errors, it will retain a link to the unaltered original.
It's a few extra steps but you should be able to automate those if you insist on retaining the original email unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea like Tim said, but if that is what you want to do then modify your j loop to something like this...

```
    For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
        Set mItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
        StrSubject = mItem.Subject
        StrSubject = StrSaveFolder & StrSubject & ".msg"
        mItem.SaveAs StrSubject, 3
    Next j
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Good point Tim, actually didn't think about that as windows doesn't accept those characters.  Thanks for the help guys